# Given $a,b,k,l$, solve $k\vec{xa}+l\vec{xb}=m\vec{xc}$ for $m$ and $c$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, vector-fields

Given two points $a$ and $b$ in a Euclidean space, and two nonzero real numbers $k,l\in\Bbb R-\{0\}$, how to find a point $c$ in this space and a nonzero real number $m\in\Bbb R-\{0\}$ such that $k\vec{xa}+l\vec{xb}=m\vec{xc}$ for all $x$ in the space? Proof of existence of the pair $c$ and $m$ is also ok if a closed-form particular solution is impossible.

I just drew a picture and got stuck by this question, because I could not see a fixed point $c$ that the vector combination $k\vec{xa}+l\vec{xb}$ always points to. Thank you for any clue for me to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\left( a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_n \right) ,b=\left( b_1,b_2,\cdots ,b_n \right) ,c=\left( c_1,c_2,\cdots ,c_n \right), x=\left( x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n \right) 
$. Then $k\vec{xa}+l\vec{xb}=m\vec{xc}$ is equivalent to say $$k\left( a_1-x_1,a_2-x_2,\cdots ,a_n-x_n \right) +l\left( b_1-x_1,b_2-x_2,\cdots ,b_n-x_n \right) =m\left( c_1-x_1,c_2-x_2,\cdots ,c_n-x_n \right) $$

EDIT: I was wrong. The correct way to proceed is as the comment shows. $m$ should be $k+l$, in order that $$[m-(k+l)]x_i=mc_i-(ka_i+lb_i)$$ holds for all $x$.

Comment: I doubt the claim that $m$ can be arbitrary and therefore we can solve by taking $m=1$. For each component, the equation is $k(a_i-x_i)+l(b_i-x_i)=m(c_i-x_i), i=1..n$, which is $[m-(k+l)]x_i=mc_i-(ka_i+lb_i)$. Since the equation holds for all $x$ and the right side is a constant, the coefficient in the left side has to be $0$ for this to be true. As a result, $m=k+l$. Plug it into the right side and we can solve $c_i=\frac{ka_i+lb_i}{k+l}$. Singular case exists as mentioned by Ross Millikan when $l=-k$. This case will be handled separately. Do you think this is the correct solution?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think now it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The equations are linear, so if it is true for $x=(1,0)$ and $x=(0,1)$ it is true everywhere.  If you write it componentwise you have two equations in two unknowns, which you should be able to solve most of the time.  Do your conditions prohibit the singular case?

Comment: It's insightful to reduce the equation for only two independent vectors (I'm still thinking of that). But after rewriting the equation componentwise, I encountered two problems: 1) we have actually three unknowns: two components $(c_1,c_2)$ of point $c$ as well as $m$. 2) I solve by subtracting the first componentwise equation from the second one, and I got $k(a_1-a_2)+l(b_1-b_2)-k-l=m(c_1-c_2)$. It seems that we cannot proceed at this point.

Comment: You are right in considering the singular case. This question is actually to prove that the union of all constant fields and all central fields constitutes a vector subspace of all vector fields. I had thought the central field $f_{(k,a)}$ is closed under addition, but the singular case ($l=-k$ that I mentioned in the comment of FFjet's answer) corresponds to a constant field, not in set of central fields any more. I did not realize that before I asked the question. Thank you for this valuable comment.

Comment: For your first, if you have one more unknown than equations, you have a degree of freedom so you have an infinite set of solutions.  You may need that in the next part.  For the second, I would expect that adding a constant field to a central field would yield a field that is neither, which violates the vector space axiom that you can add any two vectors and get another.

Comment: The solution is unique, as shown by another answer. I have just calculated the case of a central field plus a constant field using the same method in that answer. It can be shown that the sum is a (unique) central field. So, that the union is a vector subspace is established.